# What kernel version does Ubuntu Server 10.04.3 LTS come with?

Tags: kernel, lts

I want to know if a proposed hardware build will support a particular hardware RAID controller.

To be safe I want to grep the kernel source for product version codes.
I'm planning on installing Ubuntu Server 10.04.3 LTS but can't seem to figure out what kernel version it comes with.

I don't have hardware yet (or a PC even) so installing it just to see is not an option.

Does anyone know please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.6.32-34-generic

is the version in ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Comment: ofcourse, you can update to the latest kernel out there as well. Happens when you run the regular updates.